# Woocommerce - Rounding Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to fix a rounding error in Woocommerce. It appears that whenever it gets a 5 and needs to round it rounds down instead of up. My client is using two different systems that need to sync but they aren't because of this rounding.

For example one product is $14.10 normally. They have applied a 15% discount to that and Woocommerce shows the total as $11.99 where the other system show it as $11.98. I believe the issue is the discount comes to $2.115. Woocommerce sees the 5 and rounds it down to $2.11 and the other system rounds it up to $2.12.

Is there a way to change the way Woocommerce does rounding so that it will round a 5 up instead of down?

Comment: You may have better luck asking the plugin's support team directly...

Comment: I tried that and they never responded, so I thought I'd try here. :)